# URL manipulation: http://example.com/foo.jpg -> http://example.com/foo.preview.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In rails I want to wrote some code to change this url string

`https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.jpg`

to

`https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.preview.png`

Should I use regular Expression to change it?

I'm new to Regexp, anyone can show me how to do this, and how to learn this stuff

thanks

Comment: For this problem it's not necessary (see other answers), but it's surely no harm to *know* regexp...

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html for a good starting point to learn regular expressions in Ruby.

Comment: A lot of people grab onto using regexp like it's some magical all-purpose tool good for everything, and, yes, you can do a lot of magical things with regexp with the right knowledge. At the same time regexp can lead to very hard to diagnose bugs, can cause code to run more slowly due to poor searching, and be very hard to maintain, especially when the code passes on to another developer. As @eckes says, knowing how to write regexp is good, but even better is knowing when to use them. Much like writing in C or assembler, the power of regexp can blow a foot off used carelessly.

Comment: @marcog thanks again for helping me edit my question, sometime my English is not sufficient to express clearly.

Comment: @the Tin Man It's good to know. I'll use it carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the extension is of fixed length, you're better off using [string slicing](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000843).

```
url = "https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.jpg"
print url[0..-5] + ".preview" + url[-4..-1]
```

outputs

```
https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.preview.jpg
```

Or if your extensions are of variable length you can use `rindex()` to find the start of the extension.

```
url = "https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.jpeg"
dot_index = url.rindex(".")-1
print url[0..dot_index] + ".preview" + url[dot_index+1..-1]
```

outputs

```
https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.preview.jpeg
```

If you must use a regex then do it like this:

```
url = "https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.jpeg"
print url.gsub(/\.(\w{2,4})$/, ".preview.\\1")
```

outputs

```
https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.preview.jpeg
```

Comment: +1! You could use `/\.(.+?)$/` if we assume that there is always a file extension present. That would remove the need for character count limitations.

Comment: @elusive, well your regex could also match the whole string after the first `\.` since '.' will match anything and regexes are greedy. Also, you can use `*` instead of `+?`, though I don't know why you'd make it optional if you assume it's present. Maybe `/\.([\w\d]+)$/` would be ok, though that still misses cases like `.tar.gz`

Comment: @ehsanul: The `?` is to make the regular expression lazy instead of greedy. You can apply it to all quantifiers. That regular expression matches everything after the last `.`, which has to consist out of one or more characters (`+`). Another option that just came to my mind: `/\.[^\.]+?$/`

Comment: Wow, it works, but how can I write this into a method, picture.url.to_preview, I only scratch the surface of rails, right now I don't know how to right my own method in ruby. please help

Comment: @elusive Not sure how it's making the regular expression lazy. I just tried it out with a string like "was.sup.man/weljrweljwrwl.jpg" and it matches everything after "was". - http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure the file ends with .jpg, you can to

```
url = "https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.jpg"
url.gsub(".jpg", ".preview.jpg")
```

Otherwise, you can get the filename, then append the extension.

```
url = "https://img.skitch.com/20101222-kg5chjx4jetgcdeaug46hi6jpk.jpg"
ext = File.extname(url)
url.gsub(ext, ".preview{ext}")
```

Comment: +1 for `File#extname`, but why `String#gsub`? Are you expecting multiple file extensions? `String#sub` would be sufficient, right?

Comment: It is sufficient if you know the extension name in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A string replace seems to be enough.
 ".jpg" -> ".preview.png"
Unfortunately I do not know ruby.
In python it'll be

```
new_url = url.replace(".jpg",".preview.png",1)
```

I think that it'll be similar in ruby. It seems to be `sub()` instead.

```
new_url = url.sub(".jpg",".preview.png")
```

Comment: the two language is so much alike